# How can I use another PHP version?

Tags: drush

On the live server I use differents Drush and PHP versions for Drupal 8.4 and 7. I install Drush 9 to the ~/drush9 directory with `composer require drush/drush:9.*`.

On the development server and Drupal 8.4, I use the site.alias.yml file for Drush 9.

```yaml
live:
  host: hostingexample.com
  user: user
  root: /home/user/example.com/public_html/
  uri: http://example.com/
  paths:
    drush-script: '/opt/php70/bin/php /home/user/drush9/vendor/bin/drush'
```

When I run `drush @site.live ev 'print PHP_VERSION'` I get this error.

> bash: /opt/php70/bin/php /home/user/drush9/vendor/bin/drush: No such file or directory

If I add these lines in the .bash_profile file  and change `drush-script: '/home/user/drush9/vendor/bin/drush'` in site.alias.yml, I get an error because the default PHP version is 5.3.

```bash
alias php=/opt/php70/bin/php
alias drush9=~/drush9/vendor/bin/drush
```

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/user/drush9/vendor/drush/drush/src/Config/Environment.php on line 98

How can I use a different PHP for the live server and set it for Drush 9 aliases?

Comment: Check https://gist.github.com/leymannx/8e6f2fd3fe9b94aea2162cfcf417da1e

Answer (score 1):

Try editing both the `.bash_rc` and `.bash_profile` files so that you include the directory where the version of PHP you want is FIRST (before existing PATH):

(add this line or adjust if existing):

`export PATH="/opt/php70/bin:$PATH"`

As a last ditch effort, you can set the env variable drush looks for as well in these files:

`DRUSH_PHP=/opt/php70/bin/php`

Comment: The "export PATH=..." method worked for me; I set it in a bash script I use to automate deploys on a shared hosting account; the site runs Drupal 8.9, with Drush 9. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From **drush 10+** it is possible to set the PATH variable within self.site.yml, so the OP's situation would be resolved as follows:

```
live:
  host: hostingexample.com
  user: user
  root: /home/user/example.com/public_html/
  uri: http://example.com/
  paths:
    drush-script: '/home/user/drush9/vendor/bin/drush'
  env-vars:
    PATH: /opt/php70/bin/php:/bin:/usr/bin
```

**N.B.** I *do not* think this will work with drush 9 (but I'm happy to be proved otherwise)